# How to ignore lines with NUL in azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a row data in csv as shown below. The highlighted in bold letter is data for a particular cell. When I load this data in ADF data flow , the data gets shifted to next column. Is there any way to ignore the NUL ASCII so that it considers data for a cell.

**Example:-**
345435ed333241,null,CT, **NUL"15 CG street, NY, XXXXX"NUL**

[image]

[image]

My requirement is to get "34 downing street, LN, UK" under one column value.

Comment: Hi, Can you provide the screenshot of the output you getting and what you are expecting?

Comment: Added screenshot @NiharikaMoola-MT

Comment: Can you try regexReplace(column/string,'[^\x00-\x7F]+','') in derived column?